# Backbone - edit View template before render

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, backbone-views, backbone-routing

I'm trying to render a Bootstrap modal with Backbone. I need to check some HTML elements from the template (using `$('#tpl-create-details').html()`), and hide them before render, but I'm facing some problems.

1. Element is not hidden even if I add `display:none`.
2. I need to create the template as a jQuery object, so I can add `display:none` to the element, but after that I can't use the same template object because it won't be shown on the page as a Bootstrap modal but as plain HTML.

---

- Is a Backbone view the right place to do this?
- Am I doing something wrong?

---

#### View

```js
app.Views.CreateDetails = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        var template = $('#tpl-create-details').html();
        template = $(template);

        this.collection.each(function (item) {
            var customizingItem = item.toJSON();

            var fieldId = customizingItem.name;

            if (customizingItem.hidden) {
                var field = template.find('input[name=' + fieldId + ']');
                var field = $(field.get(0));
                field.parent().parent().css('display', 'none');
            }
        }, this);

        this.template = _.template(template.html());
    },

    render: function () {
        var html = this.template();
        this.$el.append(html);
        return this;
    }
});
```

---

#### Router

```js
app.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        'create': 'create'
    },

    create: function () {
        var customizing = new app.Collections.Customizing();
        customizing.fetch({
            reset: true,
            success: function (collection, response, options) {
                var CreateDetailsView = new app.Views.CreateDetails({
                    collection: collection
                });
                $('#content').append(CreateDetailsView.render().$el);
                var modalAdd = this.$('#modalDetail');
                modalAdd.modal('show');
            }
        });
    }
});
```